# Is it possible to set a wildcard for $httpBackend responses?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have the following test code in AngularJS:

```
var someURL;
var dummyJSON;
$httpBackend.whenGET(someURL).respond(dummyJSON);
```

Is there a way of making this the response for a set of URLs rather than just one?
For example, I'd like it to respond with the same dummy JSON for ANY url that starts with /api/, but not ones that start with /app/. Like a wildcard URL ("/app/*") ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use regular expression in url. Check [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend#methods_whenget)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Any help in constructing this regexp? I'm having difficulty getting it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I've had luck with expressions like `whenGET(/^\/api\//)` – which means starts with `/api/`. In the regex, `^` will match the start of the string and `\/` will match a literal `/` in the URL.

If that doesn't match your requests, try `whenGET(/\/api\//)` which should match absolute URLs as well as relative URLs.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a function if you don't want to deal with regex. Something like:

```
$httpBackend.when("GET", function(url) {return url.indexOf("/api/") === 0;}
```