# $httpBackend not accepting regexp

Tags: regex, angularjs, jasmine

In my application, a call will be made on http://localhost:8888/api/lists. I can verify that this call is made by using the following calls:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET("http://localhost:8888/api/lists").respond(200, dataMock);
$httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:8888/api/lists");
```

These tests pass just fine, and $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() will pass. However, I want to be able to configure the domain called to my production API. As such, I tried switching to the following:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET("/\/api\/lists/").respond(200, dataMock);
$httpBackend.expectGET("/\/api\/lists/");
```

The test cases will then fail with the message "Error: No pending request to flush !". I have read up on the API as well as questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847813/is-it-possible-to-set-a-wildcard-for-httpbackend-responses), but I cannot figure out why it's not working in my case. Could someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enclose the regex within the double quotes which makes it to be a normal string. You should remove them, so, it will look as following:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/api\/lists/).respond(200, dataMock);
$httpBackend.expectGET(/\/api\/lists/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove quotes from Regex.